# DefineEmits in vue always return null

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

Recently, I have started using new Vue3 version of the code, however encountered few problems when using defineEmits.

Problem 1: defineEmits always returns null.

Problem 2: Receive Reference Error - "defineEmits not defined" when using it without importing from vue. Once importing from vue, error disappears. But, as per the standard, if we are using it inside setup api, no require to import it.

Can you please let me know if I am missing anything or doing something wrong?

Example of Problem 1:

```
<template>
   <div @click="onClose">This is example 1</div>
</template>
<script setup lang='ts'>
  import {defineEmits} from 'vue';
  const emit = defineEmits(['close']);//return value always null

  const onClose = conputed(()=> {
   emit('close'); // Due to null value in emit, this line throw exception
})
```

Example of Problem 2:

```
<template>
   <div @click="onClose">This is example 1</div>
</template>
<script setup lang='ts'>
  const emit = defineEmits(['close']);//error - ReferenceError - deinfeEmits not defined

  const onClose = conputed(()=> {
   emit('close'); 
})
</script>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yi9nfx?file=src/App.vue. What's the vue version you are using ?

Comment: The example 2 is the one you should be using since you no longer have to import `defineEmits` and `defineProps`. But update your vue version because most probably you have an old version

Comment: @Psidom Using V3.2.19

Comment: @roliroli yes, I was using example 1 to avoid error from example 2. However, I completely agree that we should use without importing it. Current vue version is V3.2.19